# In Big-O terms if O(n-1) is the same thing as O(n) then why in the master theorem is T(n-1) not equal T(n)?

Tags: math, big-o, recurrence, master-theorem

Ok So I'm pretty new to CS and was recently learning about Big-O, Theta, and Omega as well as the master theorem and in lecture I saw that this was not the case for some reason and was wondering why is that?

Comment: An O(whatever) computation can specify a minimum value of n for which the performance bound holds.  Thus, there's no problem of predicting impossibly low times for degenerate cases, such as trying to perform an NlgN sort when N is 1 (but lgN is zero).

Comment: Also the Big-O is about the limit for the behaviour of an algorithm as the number approaches infinity.  Infinity = infinity -1 = infinity/2 so O(n) = O(n-1) = O(n/2)   But the master theorem is about how to make a recurrence relation for the amount of work done by an algorithm - it has nothing to do with a limit approaching infinity so you can't use the simplifications that infinity allows.

Comment: Ohh that makes so much sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although both O(n) and T(n) use capital letters on the outside and lower-case n in the middle, they represent fundamentally different concepts.

If you’re analyzing an algorithm using a recurrence relation, it’s common to let T(n) denote the amount of time it takes for the algorithm to complete on an input of size n. As a result, we wouldn’t expect T(n) to be the same as T(n-1), since, in most cases, algorithms take longer to run when you give them larger inputs.

More generally, for *any* function f, if you wanted to claim that f(n) = f(n-1), you’d need to explain why you could assume this because this generally isn’t the case.

The tricky bit here is that when we write O(n), it looks like we’re writing a function named O and passing in the argument n, but the notation means something totally different. The notation O(n) is a placeholder for “some function that, when the inputs gets really big, is bounded from above by a multiple of n.” Similarly, O(n-1) means “some function that, when the inputs get really big, is bounded from above by a multiple of n-1.” And it happens to be the case that any function that’s bounded above by a multiple of n is also bounded from above by a multiple of n-1, which is why O(n) and O(n-1) denote the same thing.

Hope this helps!